# Which nations own tracking ships for support of rocket launches?

Tags: launch, tracking

This wikipedia [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_ship) of tracking ships contains ships of the following nations: China, France, Russia and USA.

Are there no other missile range instrumentation ships for support of space operations of other nations, for instance Japan, India, Great Britan and North Korea?

I remember having seen this ship, the Monge in the harbour of Brest at the English Channel's French coast about 20 years ago.
[image]

Some month later, this ship was mentioned in German TV news, France has admitted the existance of a secret surveillance ship, the Monge. I had to laugh, the existance and purpose of such a ship could not be hidden, especially in the navy harbour of Brest easily seen from civilian areas of Brest

Comment: Are you asking about tracking/surveillance ships in general or only those being used to support space missions?